# window.opener issue in ios chrome browser

Tags: javascript, ios, google-chrome

I have a popup window which opensup on clicking a button, after a set of operations i will be closing the popup and redirect the parent to window to particular URL, i used window.opener for this approach, its works fine in all browser except IOS chrome. Please provide the solution to resolve the issue

In IOS chrome, the child window is not closed and the redirect happens in the same. My assumption is that, the ELSE condition is getting executed

```
function CallParentWindowFunction(){
    var redirect_url = "postauthcode";
    if (window.opener) {
        window.opener.location.href = redirect_url;
        window.opener.focus();
        window.close();
    }else{
        window.location.href = redirect_url;
    }       
}
```